# Returning NSString instead of NSURL does not cause warning

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I had a function that was supposed to return an NSURL, but I accidentally had it return an NSString.  Xcode did not issue any warnings.  Any idea why this is or how I can enable warnings for this. (It lead to a crash later in the app).  Incidentally, if I change the function to return an NSMutableDictionary, I do get a compiler warning about incompatible return types.  I am using Xcode 4.5.1.

```
-(NSURL *) urlForThing:(Thing *)thing
{
    //This is clearly a string at compile time and I would expect a warning
    //If I change this to [NSMutableDictionary alloc] I do get a warning
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"thing://url/%@", thing];
}
```

Comment: FYI: In place of the above you could use `[NSURL URLWithString:thing relativeToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"thing://url/"]]`

Answer (score 2):

Well, I suppose the short answer is that `stringWithFormat:` returns an `id`, not an `NSString`.  This doesn't make much sense to me, but it explains the lack of warning.